# How to filter an array save into a new array when the name was different

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter the array data that I get from the form.

```
var form = [
{name: "option_1", value: "A"},
{name: "code_1", value: "36743"}
{name: "option_2", value: "D"},
{name: "code_2", value: "36723"}
{name: "option_3", value: "C"},
{name: "code_3", value: "36543"}
{name: "option_4", value: "B"},
{name: "code_4", value: "36443"}
...
]
```

I want to filter array by name like this

```
var option = [ "A", "D", "C", "B"]
var code = [36743, 36723, 36543, 36443]
```

but I don't how because there is a number in the attribute name

Answer (score 5):

You can `filter` form array using regular expression then select the desired fields using `map` function as following:

```js
var form = [
  {name: "option_1", value: "A"},
  {name: "code_1", value: "36743"},
  {name: "option_2", value: "D"},
  {name: "code_2", value: "36723"},
  {name: "option_3", value: "C"},
  {name: "code_3", value: "36543"},
  {name: "option_4", value: "B"},
  {name: "code_4", value: "36443"}
];

let options = form.filter(a => /option_\d+/.test(a.name)).map(a => a.value);
let codes = form.filter(a => /code_\d+/.test(a.name)).map(a => Number(a.value));

console.log(options, codes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var form = [
{name: "option_1", value: "A"},
{name: "code_1", value: "36743"},
{name: "option_2", value: "D"},
{name: "code_2", value: "36723"},
{name: "option_3", value: "C"},
{name: "code_3", value: "36543"},
{name: "option_4", value: "B"},
{name: "code_4", value: "36443"}];

/*
var data = form.filter((item) => {
  return parseInt(item.value) ? item.value : '';
}) */

var data =form.filter((item) => {
  return item.name.includes('code');
}).map(a=>a.value);

console.log(data);


var data1 =form.filter((item) => {
  return item.name.includes('option')
}).map(a=>a.value);

console.log(data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```